# Ruby on Rails Concurrency

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Is Ruby on Rails a single-threaded application? I feel that it does not support any concurrency, especially when I am doing mysql queries.

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.11 with Phusion Passenger (all provided by Bluehost). Also, this is what I am using for my development server looks like

```
[2013-03-19 10:42:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-03-19 10:42:00] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08) [universal-darwin12.0]
[2013-03-19 10:42:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=23034 port=3000
```

The following scenario seriously makes my application unusable:

Step 1: Bulk Insertion ( a lot of data ) <-- this gets stuck when the transaction is commiting the data.

Step 2: Querying from a different table of the insertion, fetching JSON objects.

I can tell this is happening from the console. I have tried increasing the "pool" ( I believed this would have increased mysql concurrent connections ) but it did not increase my performance.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Rails is single threaded, largely because MRI ruby has had poor thread concurrency support. You can try to put Rails into multi-threaded mode via:

```
config.thread_safe!
```

This will be the default in Rails 4. In general, if you need to kick off a long running process in Rails, you probably want to do the bulk of the work in separate background process using something like [DelayedJob](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job), [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [Beanstalk](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd). How soon the results are available for other threads will depend on how long it takes to finish and whether the whole bulk insert is in a single transaction, or several smaller transactions.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, the last sentence really confused me, does it relate to using the background processes or without the background processes? Would the background processes that you suggested prevent the "waiting" of the other mysql operations?

Comment: If you do the bulk insert in a separate background process, the user who triggered the insert in the browser won't have to wait for it to complete, and that rails worker process won't be tied up. But, if the bulk insert happens in a single transaction, it doesn't matter how you run it, nothing else will be able to see the data because mysql will hide it until the transaction completes. This is good, because until the transaction finishes, it might get rolled back; that's the main point of using a transaction in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's serial threaded by default (handles one request all the way through, then another).  To enable multithreaded, specify a pool size like you did, and run

```
config.threadsafe!
```

in your environment.rb type files.

I don't think this will affect the scenario you describe, though, that sounds more like MySql is "waiting" for the other commit to finish before it continues with its own insertions.